# How to retrieve the value of header object in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, http-headers

I have some Scala code which retrieves the value from a variable in the http header.

`println("header auth: ", request.headers.get(myParam))`

This shows the following in the console

> (header auth: ,Some(xxx_made_up_stuff_xxx))

What I actually need is the value inside `Some()`
I have tried `toString()` but that did not change anything.

I am very very new to Scala, so apologies is this is very basic.

Comment: You need to understand the meaning and the purpose of the Option[T] type constructor. In functional programming it is used for dealing with absent values instead of comparing the value to null. This has a lot of benefits and can help you produce cleaner code with less defects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.headers.get(myParam)` returns on `Option`. To get the value inside you can use `.getOrElse`, `.fold` or the unsafe `.get`:

```scala
request.headers.get(myParam).getOrElse("No header for key myParam")

request.headers.get(myParam).fold("No header for key myParam")(identity)

request.headers.get(myParam) // can throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException`
```